# Standard Relation in terms of partition function and beta

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

$$(\Delta E)^2 = \frac{\partial^2 \ln{Z}}{\partial \beta^2} \tag{2.29}$$

Shortly, how can I obtain this relation? I found this relation from Franz Mandl Statistical Physics

The following are related relations.
$$\bar{E} = \sum_r p_r E_r = - \frac{\partial \ln{Z}}{\partial \beta} \tag{2.26}$$
$$p_r = \frac{1}{Z} e^{- \beta E_r} \tag{2.22}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not homework-like. It is a standard stage in the development of equilibrium SM, and the asker clearly needs help understanding it.

Comment: Yes, as you wrote, I try to derive steps from the book. Thanks for your help, I got it. I should write my attempted calculation but I am not good at LaTeX. I need to learn it.

Comment: Good: I'm glad you've understood. I like Mandl's book. It uses very much the same approach as the more widely known book by Reif, but is more compact and succinct than Reif. Re MathJax/Latex:  I think you'll find it a joy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Delta E$ is the standard deviation of the energies in the distribution. It is defined by
$$(\Delta E)^2= \overline {(E_r-\overline E)^2}\ \ =\ \ \overline{E^2}-\overline E^2.$$
Mandl gives hints for deriving (2.26). I'll show you what he means...
$$\overline E=\sum_r E_r p_r=\sum_r E_r \frac 1Z e^{-\beta E_r}=-\sum_r\frac 1Z \frac \partial {\partial \beta}e^{-\beta E_r}=-\frac 1Z \frac {\partial} {\partial \beta} \sum_r e^{-\beta E_r}=-\frac 1Z \frac {\partial Z} {\partial \beta}=-\frac {\partial} {\partial\beta} \ln Z$$

Can you not follow a similar procedure to obtain an expression for $\overline{E^2}$ in terms of $Z$? That will enable you to find $(\Delta E)^2$ using the definition I have given.

You might prefer to start by expanding the right hand side of (2.29), working carefully through the differentiations, at some point substituting $Z=\sum_r e^{-\beta E_r}$. Remember that two differentiations wrt $\beta$ will bring down a multiplied $E_r^2$ from the exponential.